# I need to insert 1 millions of records from one table to another tables in 2 batches , 500k in each in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

Hi Can any one please help me with a procedure  for inserting 7 million records for 7 years (million records each year) in loop in MYSQL,

I need to insert in a batch of 500,000 for each batch .

Data is there in table "Archive_data", need to insert in "Stg_table"

Archive data has yearly sales, i want to write a loop in MYSQL looping on Year and insert in a batch of 500K each

i tried

```
insert into SDL_Stg_Bill_Details
select SDL_Id, Rec_Is_Processed, concat(Bill_Header_Key,'_',Row_Num), Bill_Header_Key,Row_Num from (
SELECT SDL_Id, Rec_Is_Processed, Bill_Details_Key, Bill_Header_Key,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Bill_Header_Key order by SDL_Id ) Row_Num
FROM PANTALOONS_SOLUS_PROD.SDL_Stg_Bill_Details_Archive 
where EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM Bill_Date) in ('201406',
'201407',
'201408',
'201409',
'201410') ff
```

i am getting lock wait time out exceeded error if i am trying 7 M records
at once

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your data saved? In another database or in files... why not write a simple python/java loop to do it with MySQL connector?

Comment: my data is saved in another table, i need to do few calculations and insert into another table, which is taking lot of time, i need to write it only using my sql loop.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Write your procedure in the question and explain the errors that you are getting. Maybe we can help you...

Comment: *I need to insert in a batch of 500,000 for each batch.* Why do you NEED in this?  *which is taking lot of time* And? While using batches it will be even more long process.

Comment: if not for 500k btch , please tell me any other solution also, it would be helpful for me  @Akina

Comment: Is the only purpose of all this to create a compound key?

Comment: no, from staging table, data needs to go to one recommendation algorithm, which is very long story, i only need help to dump those rows from archive to stg @P.Salmon

Comment: Why? Who said you had to use batches of 500K? What's their plan if that's too many? Ask. Enquire.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but I hope with some tweaks it might help you:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE CopyDataInBatch()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x  INT;
    DECLARE y  INT;
    SET x = 1;
    SET y = x + 10000;
    the_loop :  LOOP
        IF  x > 1000000 THEN  /* Use the number of rows you wanted to copy*/
            LEAVE  the_loop;
        END  IF;
        INSERT INTO table_in_which_copying (col_name_1, col_name_2)
        SELECT (col_name_1, col_name_2) FROM table_from_which_copying
        ORDER BY (col_name_1)
        LIMIT x, y;
        SET  x = x + 10000;
        SET  y = y + 10000;
        SELECT "Copied 10000 rows"; /* Only for testing... better remove it(?)*/
    END LOOP;
END $ 
DELIMITER ;
```